# Enable Android Usb Testing on Hp Phone

Tags: android, android-studio, usb

I have a hp slate 6 voicetab running android 4.4 and I would like to use it to test an android app that I am developing. The Android phone is not showing up on the list of devices next to the emulator.

Can someone please help me.

P.S I am using android studio and running windows 8.1

Comment: Did you install USB driver for Android phone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `USB Debugging Mode` and `Allow Mock Locations` turned-on on your android device. To do that go to settings on the device and scroll down to developer options, then enable usb debugging. Also enable `Allow mock locations`.

Note if `Developer options` is not visible, enable it by going to `About Phone` and tap on the `build number` repeatedly 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it working. I used a software called ADBDriver installer, and I disabled the windows certificate check, then enabled developer options on the phone and it was able to show. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped you or at least upvote the answer you found useful. Thanks.